# Confgure pax-exam with --definitionURL

Tags: pax-exam, pax, pax-runner

From [Dmytro Pishchukhin's blog](http://blog.knowhowlab.org/2010/05/pax-runner-and-exam-new-osgi-framework.html) I learned that pax-exam's runner can configure itself from an extension xml containing platform definition in the following way: 
`@Configuration
    public static Option[] configurePlatform() {
        return options(
                ...
                rawPaxRunnerOption("--definitionURL", "file:platform-equinox-3.6M7.xml")
        );
    }`
but it seems `rawPaxRunnerOption` has been deprecated and removed. Is there a way to load this definition these days? (Documentation at [Pax Runner Docs](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxexam/Configuration+Options#ConfigurationOptions-rawPaxRunnerOption)) doesn't seem to be updated.

Comment: Pax Runner is not a runner for Pax Exam. Since release 3.0.0, Pax Exam no longer supports or uses Pax Runner.

Comment: Pax Runner itself is virtually unsupported these days.